# Nullreference exception does not show up when async Task discarded

Tags: asynchronous, logging, .net-core, task-parallel-library

I have an async Task with a method signature defined like this:

```
public async Task<bool> HandleFooAsync()
```

When executing this task in an async way and discarding the results, exceptions happening in this task do not show up in our logs.

```
_ = _slackResponseService.HandleFooAsync();
```

When I await the execution of the task I see the error in our logs

```
var result = await _slackResponseService.HandleFooAsync();
```

Is this expected behaviour? Is there a way to achieve a solution in between: "do not wait for the result, but log errors nevertheless.." ? We invested hours debugging our logging setup, just to learn that our logging setup is correct, but `discard` means in dotnet that everything is discarded - even logs. Which is a quite a new perspective for us, coming from a Python background.

Our logging setup follows the default logging setup for dotnet core 3 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: ASP.NET takes the "forget" part of "fire and forget" very literally. Which is why "fire and forget" is almost never the correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is an expected behavior. Call in that way can be considered like an anti-pattern. You can read about it [C# Async Antipatterns](https://markheath.net/post/async-antipatterns)

You need something which is called as "Fire and forget". One of its implementation can be find in repo [AsyncAwaitBestPractices](https://github.com/brminnick/AsyncAwaitBestPractices) (nuget available too).

Answer (score 0):

A Task in .net and netcore is meant to be awaited. If it is not awaited, the scope might be destroyed before the async method has finished.

If you want to run tasks in the background and not wait for a result you can use BackgroundService in .netcore or a third party such as Hangfire which supports fire and forget jobs out of the box

https://medium.com/@daniel.sagita/backgroundservice-for-a-long-running-work-3debe8f8d25b
https://www.hangfire.io/

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to subscribe to the [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception) event. It is not ideal because the event is raised when the faulted `Task` is garbage collected, which may happen long after the actual fault.

Another solution could be to use an extension method every time a task is fired and forgotten. Like this:

```cs
_slackResponseService.HandleFooAsync().FireAndForget();
```

Here is a basic implementation of the `FireAndForget` method:

```cs
public async static void FireAndForget(this Task task)
{
    try
    {
        await task;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log the exception here
    }
}
```